# C# WPF DataGrid.RowStyle set column style

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Is it possible to affect a style/Behaviorto a specified column in a specified row in WPF C#?

Right now I have this:

```
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Status}" Value="2">
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="0"/>
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="false" />
                    </DataTrigger>
```

The problem right now is, that the entire row is disabled. I would like just the first column to be disabled in some circumstances.

This is the column, I would like to disable:

```
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Details" Width="100">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Click="ShowDetails">Details</Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works (disabling 2nd column "Y" if value of "X" is 3):

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="X" Binding="{Binding X}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Y" Binding="{Binding Y}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding X}" Value="3">
                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thx for helping me. I get the point, but in my case, I have DataGridTemplateColumn and I do not know how to do a binding. Check my edited question.

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Details" Width="100">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button IsEnabled ="{Binding boolEnabled}" Click="ShowDetails">Details</Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```